# How do I successfully deploy the flask app on ec2?

Tags: nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, ubuntu-22.04

We created one web app in flask, and for users authentication we used the aws cognito hosted UI, and I am able to successfully run the app on my localhost.

But when I tried to deploy it on ec2 ubuntu using nginx server, I can only access the cognito hosted UI of my app, but after successful authentication in cognito, it is supposed to redirect to my dashboard page, which is happening when i am running the code on localhost, but on ec2 instance it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I tried below things:

1. I setup the virtual environment, and installed all the packages.
2. I setup the security group port as well in ec2.
3. I setup the gunicorn configuration file.
4. I setup the nginx, and congiguration file

I tried to run my project with below commands:

*sudo systemctl stop project_name*

*sudo systemctl restart project_name*

*sudo systemctl daemon-reload*

*sudo systemctl start project_name*

*sudo systemctl enable project_name*

*sudo systemctl start nginx*

*sudo systemctl enable nginx*

*sudo systemctl restart nginx*

Any guidance would be very helpful.

[image: gunicorn configuration file]

[image: nginx configuration file]

Answer (score 1):

Try running the app by passing the host like this in your app

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: I am already running the app with that port.

Comment: have you explicitly provided like this tho?

you are running it as follows right :

`$ flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

As if this is not the issue, all I can think of is your inbound rules in EC2

Comment: I tried with the command you mentioned as well.

Comment: Still there is a error

Comment: Even the inbound rules, i checked many times